# How to start a node application in CentOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, vagrant

I am trying to learn backbone with udacity's tutorial. There are two links for installing this application.

[FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone)

[FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server)

Under `FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone`, the instructions tell me to do this:

```
Set up the project

clone this repo
cd into the newly cloned project
install Bower dependencies via bower install
Set up the server

clone the backend server
launch the binary for your platform
don't forget the --www flag pointing to the UdaciMeals Backbone project you just cloned above
check out that project's Running the server section of its README for specific details

View the app

Using your favorite browser, load http://localhost:8000/ and
```

For the `FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server` project, a snippet of  the `Readme.md` has the following instruction:

```
The binaries directory contains builds for Windows, Mac OS X ("darwin"), and Linux. 
Run the appropriate server program to start the server, supplying 
the --www= flag to point to your front-end code 
(e.g. on Mac OS X use ./server_darwin_amd64 --www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone)
```

The example is with Mac Osx obviously but how do I accomplish this command in CentOS `./server_darwin_amd64 --www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the `binaries` directory in the repo](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server/tree/master/binaries), the answer would seem to be:

```
./server_linux_amd64 --www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone
```

This seems to assume you are running the command from the same `binaries` directory itself and that the relative path to the `FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone` directory from there is as specified. (If you are following along with the tutorial, that latter assumption will hopefully be true.)

Comment: Yup I just found it now as well. Thanks for confirming, should have dug a little deeper. I'll mark the answer in 3 min.